# Windows Server 2008 R2: change account type from command line?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, user-accounts

I have a need to add a user to a Windows Server 2008 R2 box, and make that user an administrator. Basically, I want to automate the second step of this process:

```
1. net user MyUser password /add
2. Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Add or Remove user accounts -> MyUser -> Change the account type
```

Google is giving me pretty much nothing, but it's possible I'm not searching for the right terms.

Disclaimer: This is not anything I'm doing on a business production box, it's for a legacy application I need for development purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
net group gropuname username /add
```

see `net help group` for more details. To make a user an administrator, they need to be a member of the machine's `Administrators` group.